# Why Does the Parent Go to Width=100% When I Display Div?

Tags: css

I'm developing the below responsive calendar (I removed a bunch of JavaScript for simplicity). Everything is great except when I show the `details` div under a week, the container changes to 100% width and everything jumps to the left. Why does this happen? I've tried every CSS combination I can think of with `width: auto, inherit, etc.` and unless I set the width to a static value I get this undesired effect, but then I lose the responsiveness. What am I missing?

Click on any day to see the effect:

```js
function closeDetailDivs() {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('details');
  for (let el of elements) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function handleCalendarDayClick() {
  let detailsEl = event.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.details');

  if (detailsEl.style.display == 'flex') {
    closeDetailDivs();
  } else {
    detailsEl.style.display = 'flex';
  }
}

const calendarDays = document.querySelectorAll('.day');

for (let i = 0; i < calendarDays.length; i++) {
  calendarDays[i].addEventListener("click", handleCalendarDayClick);
}
```

```css
.calendarContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
}

.calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

.calendarData {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 10vw;
  padding-top: 4vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.yearHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  cursor: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.calendarHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.calendarHeaderDays {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.calendarHeaderDays li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 2vw;
  background: rgb(117, 11, 11);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
  user-select: none;
}

.top {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: white;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.day {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #efefef;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.day:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.day .clicked {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dayElSpan {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.details {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 57vw;
  background: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  padding: 2vh 1vw;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgb(192, 192, 192) transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.details--details p {
  line-height: 0.5;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarContainer">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendarHeader">
      <div class="yearHeader">2020</div>
      <ul class="calendarHeaderDays">
        <li>Sat</li>
        <li>Sun</li>
        <li>Mon</li>
        <li>Tue</li>
        <li>Wed</li>
        <li>Thu</li>
        <li>Fri</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="arrow top" id="upArrow">△</div>
      <div class="days">
        <div class="day week1Day1"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">23</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">24</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">25</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">26</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">27</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">28</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">29</span></div>
        <div class="details" style="display: none;">
          <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="details--details"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="days">
        <div class="day week2Day1"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">30</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">31</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan1st">01</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">02</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">03</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">04</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">05</span></div>
        <div class="details" data-day="3" style="display: none;">
          <div class="pointer" style="left: 28.1vw;"></div>
          <div class="details--details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow bottom" id="downArrow">▽</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add `align-items: center;` to `.calendarHeader`

```
.calendarHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* Add align items */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

2. Add `justify-content: center;` to `.days`

```
.days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center; /* Add justify-content */
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
```

```js
function closeDetailDivs() {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('details');
  for (let el of elements) {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function handleCalendarDayClick() {
  let detailsEl = event.currentTarget.parentNode.querySelector('.details');

  if (detailsEl.style.display == 'flex') {
    closeDetailDivs();
  } else {
    detailsEl.style.display = 'flex';
  }
}

const calendarDays = document.querySelectorAll('.day');

for (let i = 0; i < calendarDays.length; i++) {
  calendarDays[i].addEventListener("click", handleCalendarDayClick);
}
```

```css
.calendarContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 2vh 2vw;
}

.calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1100px;
}

.calendarData {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-width: 10vw;
  padding-top: 4vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

.yearHeader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  cursor: text;
  user-select: text;
}

.calendarHeader {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center; /* Add align items */
  justify-content: center;
}

.calendarHeaderDays {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.calendarHeaderDays li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 2vw;
  background: rgb(117, 11, 11);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.arrow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 6px;
  user-select: none;
}

.top {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: white;
}

.days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center; /* Add justify-content */
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.day {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 8vw;
  height: 4vw;
  margin-right: 3px;
  border-right: 3px solid #efefef;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.day:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.day .clicked {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.dayElSpan {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.details {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 57vw;
  background: rgb(192, 192, 192);
  padding: 2vh 1vw;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pointer {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -2px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgb(192, 192, 192) transparent;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.details--details p {
  line-height: 0.5;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendarContainer">
  <div class="calendar">
    <div class="calendarHeader">
      <div class="yearHeader">2020</div>
      <ul class="calendarHeaderDays">
        <li>Sat</li>
        <li>Sun</li>
        <li>Mon</li>
        <li>Tue</li>
        <li>Wed</li>
        <li>Thu</li>
        <li>Fri</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="arrow top" id="upArrow">△</div>
      <div class="days">
        <div class="day week1Day1"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">23</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">24</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">25</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">26</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">27</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">28</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">29</span></div>
        <div class="details" style="display: none;">
          <div class="pointer"></div>
          <div class="details--details"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="days">
        <div class="day week2Day1"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">30</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">31</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan1st">01</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">02</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">03</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">04</span></div>
        <div class="day"><span class="dayElSpan dayTextSpan">05</span></div>
        <div class="details" data-day="3" style="display: none;">
          <div class="pointer" style="left: 28.1vw;"></div>
          <div class="details--details">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow bottom" id="downArrow">▽</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The div calendarHeader still jumps to 100% width, although there is no visible effect. Can anyone explain what is causing that?

Comment: The div calendarHeader is always 100% width as default div has 100% width. If you open the devtool to see, it is always 100% width.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I find with adding `width: 66%;` to the calendar div and your suggestions above, I get exactly what I want. Thank you!

Comment: Np. Glad to help.